# How to create multipage form and redirect to specific URL based on inpput?

Tags: customization, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I want to create multi page form, where first page will take information about user, second page will take information about product which he likes and third page user will subscribe either one time or monthly. Based on one time or monthly selection I would like to redirect to appropriate URL. Which is best solution for this scenario.

Comment: If you're using Gravity Forms (as your question's tags suggest), you should be able to set different confirmation pages or redirections based on the selections made in the form. For more info, you should contact Gravity Forms' support, as third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: If not, using php get method, a submit button acting as a next button (using the ISSET rule to pass values to the next page) can work, no plugin needed just add this as a shortcode to your functions.php file